# Twitter Bootstrap: Why the z-index: 2 for some states?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap for my mobile web application. There are certain layers that overlap others when they slide-in or slide-out of viewport. These are the situations, when the z-index on these layers plays a crucial role.

Often, my screens, with perfectly laid out z-orders, are thrown out of order because of the use of `z-index: 2`, for example in the following style from bootstrap.css:

```
.btn-group > .btn:hover,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn:hover,
.btn-group > .btn:focus,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn:focus,
.btn-group > .btn:active,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn:active,
.btn-group > .btn.active,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn.active {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I know I could override them in my own style sheets, but I'm beginning to wonder where the motivation for setting the `z-index` explicitly comes from.

I understand the motivation in setting `z-index: 1000` in `.dropdown-menu` for instance. But I'm at a loss to understand why `:hover`, `:focus` & `:active` state for `btn-group > .btn` needs `z-index: 2`.

I'm sure if it's there, it's there for a reason. I'm just missing the point.

An example screen shot is attached. This is from an `active` button in a `btn-group` on a layer below the current. This `btn-group` has several other buttons which get hidden when the current layer overlaps the one below. However, this active button tears through.

[image]

Answer (score -5, accepted):

They use `z-index: 2;` on those elements so it appears on top of other peer elements with z-index of 1 or less, below any peer elements with `z-index: 3;` or more, and on the same level as any `z-index: 2;`

Comment: I understand, it puts those elements on top of peers, but why do we need that? The peers are not overlapping anyway?

Comment: @CodePoet Well, this is why I try to avoid using css frameworks. They add a lot of unecessary stuff, and you can end up doing more work than just writing it from scratch.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. The OP is asking _why_.